# Webscraper in Python

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping

My question is if it is possible to get a number that is inside a span like this:

```
<html junk>
 <div class="test">
     <span>
     55
     </span>
 </div>
</html junk>
```

As you can see the span has no class or id.

My current code which is just the default code for a scraper (removed User-Agent and URL):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = ''

headers = {"User-Agent": ''}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#Here is where the "55" should be found (the number is going to change over time so im not excactly looking for it
title = soup.find('') 

print(title)
```

Comment: So what is your question?  What does your code do?  What doesn't work?  Even with the redacted values filled in, it doesn't look like it does anything but look for a zero-length string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're trying to get the number between the two span tags? If so, you can do this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = ''

headers = {"User-Agent": ''}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

#Here is where the "55" should be found (the number is going to change over time so im not excactly looking for it
title = soup.find('span').getText() 

print(title)
```

Comment: I am getting a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText' with that

Comment: Sorry, replace `.getText()` with `.text`